# How to get Microsoft.Extensions.Http in COM+ to work?

Tags: com+, .net-4.7, ihttpclientfactory

We use IHttpClientFactory in a .NET 4.7 COM+ class. To be able to use IHttpClientFactory, we added the Nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Http version 7.0, which installed the following dlls in the packages directory:

```
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
System.Buffers.4.5.1\lib\net461\System.Buffers.dll
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.7.0.0\lib\net462\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
System.Memory.4.5.5\lib\net461\System.Memory.dll
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.6.0.0\lib\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.5.4\lib\net461\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net47\System.ValueTuple.dll
```

We installed these dlls in the GAC with gacutil.
Upon calling the method HttpClient.PostAsync we get the exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

1. What do we have to do, so that COM+ can find this dll?
2. Is it safe to install the above dlls in the GAC on a production server with Windows Server 2012?
3. The name "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" does not suggest safeness. Is it really safe for a production environment?
4. Is it safe to use HttpClientFactory in a COM+ class?
5. The following solution demonstrates the problem:
   https://github.com/pappasa/TestHttpClientFactory

Best regards,

Alexandros

Comment: [There is no version 7.0 of the `System.Net.Http` NuGet package - the most recent is 4.3.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/#versions-body-tab) - why and how does your post say you're using version 7.0?.

Comment: Your GitHub repo only contains VB.NET projects (and the C# ASP.NET project) - I don't see any actual use of COM+ beyond an `Import System.EnterpriseServices` line.

Comment: @Dai Well he clearly has ```Microsoft.Extensions.Http.7.0.0\lib\net462\Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll``` being used from the output shown. And I could find this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/7.0.0

Comment: @majixin The OP wrote _"we added the Nuget package `System.Net.Http` version 7.0"_ - they didn't mention `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` by name.

Comment: OP, why are you talking about COM+ at all here? I don't see how COM+ is relevant at all here: you can accomplish what you want with normal assembly references, and you shouldn't be touching the GAC at all.

Comment: @Dai Correct, but they've shown ```Microsoft.Extensions.Http``` in the output, so I expect the OP is conflating them.

Comment: Excuse me, we added Nuget package Microsoft.Extensions.Http (which contains IHttpClientFactory). I erroneously wrote System.Net.Http.

Comment: Our business logic runs on COM+, because we need distributed transactions, and therefore, we have to make REST calls from COM+. You can see that the class APIAccess inherits from ServicedComponent, and in the post-build events, the APIAccess project is registered in the GAC (with gacutil) and in COM+ (with regsvcs)

Comment: @Alex Distributed Transactions don't depend on COM+ - have you seen  the types in [the `System.Transactions` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions)?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "make REST calls **from** COM+"? All of your posted code is VB.NET or C#, which means it runs within the CLR, and not from within a native (i.e. not-.NET) COM+ host-process - (unless it is? in which case you haven't posted anything that suggests that...)

Comment: Yes, I know that you can do distributed transactions with System.Transactions, but our whole business logic runs now on COM+, and we cannot change that for the time beeing. We are planning to migrate away from COM+, but only in two or three years.

Comment: The posted code, and in particular the class APIAccess is in VB.NET and inherits from System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent, that means, it runs in COM+. I use COM+ as a synonym for Component Services. That means, it runs in the process dllhost.exe. Not only native libraries may run in COM+, .NET libraries may also run in COM+ (or else Component Services)